# How to get the Tololtip Tail for Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

**HTML**

```
<div id="MyForm">
    <a> <img src="ImageMenu.png" /></a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="selected" href="#">One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Two</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Three</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On clicking the **ImageMenu.png**, I'm displaying a Menu using **JQuery**. How to Get the **Tooltip tail** (Uparrow) just under the Menuimage using **CSS**?

Comment: A fiddle would be very useful for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking something like this...

My Image

- One
- Two
- Three

CSS contains...

## mymenu a

{
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    color: #222;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: bold 12px/25px Arial, Helvetica;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}

## mymenu li:hover > a

{
    color: #222;
}

*html #mymenu li a:hover /* IE6 */
{
    color: #222;
}

## mymenu li:hover > ul

{
    display: block !important;
}

/* Sub-menu */

```
#mymenu ul
{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    display: none !important;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    width:150px;
    z-index: 99999;    
    background: #fff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#555, #888);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #888),color-stop(1, #555));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#555, #888);    
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#555, #888); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#555, #888);    
    background: linear-gradient(#555, #888);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(255,255,255,.5);   
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}


#mymenu ul li
{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #111111, 0 2px 0 #777777;
}

#mymenu ul li:last-child
{   
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;    
}

#mymenu ul a
{    
    padding: 7px !important;
    height: 10px;
    width: 135px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 1.8em !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-weight:normal;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: none;
    color:#fff;
    text-transform: none;
    text-align:left;

}

*html #mymenu ul a /* IE6 */
{    
    height: 10px;
}

*:first-child+html #mymenu ul a /* IE7 */
{    
    height: 10px;
}
#mymenu ul a:hover
{
    background: #d7d7d7;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#d7d7d7,  #d7d7d7);    
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#d7d7d7), to(#d7d7d7));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#d7d7d7,  #d7d7d7);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#d7d7d7,  #d7d7d7);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#d7d7d7,  #d7d7d7);
    background: linear-gradient(#d7d7d7,  #d7d7d7);
    color:#222;
    text-shadow: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:#222;
}
#mymenu ul li:first-child > a
{
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

#mymenu ul li:first-child > a:after
{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 30px;
    top: -8px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #444;
}

#mymenu ul li:first-child a:hover:after
{
    border-bottom-color: #d7d7d7; 
}

#mymenu ul li:last-child > a
{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

WORKING DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nPeaV/7430/

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

**Demo Link**

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-bubble.html

**Source Code**

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/